# Plpgsql ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table when trying to insert

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

Every time I try to insert something in table SaleosOrderDetail I get the following error:

> ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "salesorderdetail" LINE 1:
>   SELECT CustomerID FROM SalesOrderHeader WHERE SalesOrderDeta...
>                                                          QUERY:  SELECT CustomerID FROM SalesOrderHeader WHERE SalesOrderDetail.SalesOrderID =
>   SalesOrderHeader.SalesOrderID CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function
>   new_order_detail() line 6 at SQL statement
>
> ********** Error **********
>
> ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "salesorderdetail" SQL
>   state: 42P01 Context: PL/pgSQL function new_order_detail() line 6 at
>   SQL statement

The code is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION new_order_detail()
RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
DECLARE CustID INT;
BEGIN


    SELECT CustomerID FROM SalesOrderHeader WHERE SalesOrderDetail.SalesOrderID = SalesOrderHeader.SalesOrderID INTO custID;
    UPDATE Customer SET number_of_items = number_of_items + 1 WHERE CustomerID = custID ;



END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;


DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS new_order ON SalesOrderDetail;

CREATE TRIGGER new_order
    AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON SalesOrderDetail
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE new_order_detail();
```

Comment: As the error says, the error is in the first SELECT statement in the trigger function. You're trying to use a table (`SalesOrderDetail`) that you are not selecting from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try replace :

```
   SELECT CustomerID FROM SalesOrderHeader WHERE SalesOrderDetail.SalesOrderID = SalesOrderHeader.SalesOrderID INTO custID;
```

by :

```
SELECT INTO custID CustomerID FROM SalesOrderHeader WHERE SalesOrderHeader.SalesOrderID=NEW.SalesOrderID;
```

Comment: Worked like a charm!! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You are missing table SalesOrderDetail. Probably you want:

```
SELECT CustomerID 
    FROM SalesOrderHeader, SalesOrderDetail
   WHERE SalesOrderDetail.SalesOrderID = SalesOrderHeader.SalesOrderID
INTO custID;
```

This form of JOIN is obsolete. Use modern form instead:

```
SELECT CustomerID 
    FROM SalesOrderHeader
         JOIN SalesOrderDetail
         ON SalesOrderDetail.SalesOrderID = SalesOrderHeader.SalesOrderID
INTO custID;
```

Because PostgreSQL SQL is case insensitive, then camel notation is not recommended. Use underscore character instead:

Wrong: CustomerID, Good: custmer_id

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice!